# Definition of a Limit

Tags: limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Prove that $ \ln\left(e +\frac{1}{n}\right) \to 1$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

I know I must show $\exists$ $n > N$ such that $\left|\ln\left(e +\frac{1}{n}\right)-1\right|< \varepsilon $

But I am having difficulty simplifying the expression and isolating for n. Is there an elementary log rule that can be used?

Comment: Maybe you can try using the fact that $e^{ln(e+1/n)}=e+1/n$. Then there is a result that by continuity, $lim_{x \rightarrow a}(f(x)=f(a)$

Comment: You might want to have another look at the *definition* of continuity, since the version you give in the post is horribly mangled.

Comment: How is the version in the post mangled?

Comment: @user99680 Seriously? Well, put the definition of limit near this and compare. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did: I don't understand, put the definition of limit near what? Why don't you then please write the comment below the post so I can understand better what you mean? I am basically stating that continuity allows to exchange limits in this last respect: Lim_{x \rightarrow a)f(x)=f(Lim_{x-a}).

Comment: @user99680 Near what is written in the post, of course. (Would you be taking a comment to the question for a comment to your answer, by any chance?)

Comment: @Did: Doesn't the post just state the result that continuity implies sequential continuity: if f is continuous at x, then $[x_n \rightarrow x] \rightarrow [f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)]$?

Comment: @user99680 YOUR post might be saying that, not the question.

Comment: @Did: O.K, my post needs some change because we are considering a limit at $\infty$; let me rewrite it.

Comment: @Did: I am not sure I understand your objection; it ultimately comes down to this: ln is continuous in $( 0,\infty)$, so it is sequentially-continuous. Then , since $(e+1/n) \rightarrow e)$ , it follows that $ln(e+1/n) \rightarrow lne=1)$.

Comment: @user99680 Once again, I did not comment your post, but the question above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Rewrite as $\ln\left(e\left(1+\frac{1}{en}\right)\right)$, and then as $\ln e+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{en}\right)$. Then use the fact that for $x\gt 0$ we have $0\lt \ln(1+x)\lt x$.

Comment: Thank you very much, just have to get used to these tricks the book throws at me :D

Comment: You are welcome. Note that my answer is only useful if you are looking for an $\epsilon$-$N$ proof.  If not, the continuity argument of the other answer is superior.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good result/corollary to know about continuity: If $f$ is continuous at $x$, then: $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = x \rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x_n) = f(x)$$ In this case, the function $\ln$ is continuous at $e$ (and in an open set about $e$) , so that, applying that to $f(x)=\ln x $, we have that : $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ln(e+1/n)= \ln( e+ \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} 1/n)=\ln e $$

Edit: @Did suggested this corollary was written ambiguously, or in a mangled way: the intended point is that continuity implies sequential * continuity, which is to say that , when f is continuous at a point x, then, whenever we have $x_n \rightarrow x$, it follows that $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$.

Formally, here, we have :i) ln(x) is continuous in $( 0, \infty)$ ii) ln(x) is sequentially continuous in $(0, \infty)$ . Then we have $e+1/n \rightarrow e$, from which we conclude, using sequential continuity, that $ln(e+1/n) \rightarrow ln(e)=1$

- Or, in some cases, we use nets.

Comment: Wanted to ask, is your method still in line with using the definition to prove the answer. Thanks for the useful input anyhow.

Comment: @Guest: I think so; this argument can be made into a $n -\epsilon $ argument